# Таблица, в которой значения уникальны только по своему id

Tags: mysql

У меня есть простая таблица, где каждое поле word привязано к значению id (auto increment) из другой таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE WORDS (ID_USER INT, WORD VARCHAR(30), FOREIGN KEY (ID_USER) REFERENCES USERS (ID));
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы значение word было уникальным только по отношению к его id?

То есть уникальные поля word только для своего id, а между собой с разными id могут повторяться

например, слово 'стек' с id 1 и 'стек' с id 2 могут существовать, но при добавлении 'стек' с id 2 уже нельзя было добавить

Answer (score 2):

Можно наложить unique constraint по двум полям. 
Но если у вас одно и тоже слово может встречаться у разных пользователей то получается связка многие ко многим - используйте связку через таблицу. Так вы не будете дублировать одно и то же слово для разных пользователей. Например:

```
users(user_id, ...)
words(word_id, word)
users_words( user_id, word_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить новую колонку в words и определить ее как PK, а на остальные две колонки наложить unique constraint. Тогда у тебя будет две таблицы со связью 1 ко многим

```
create or replace table USER
(
    USER_ID  int auto_increment primary key,
    username varchar(32) not null,
    constraint user_username_uindex
        unique (USERNAME)
);

create or replace table WORDS
(
    WORD_ID int auto_increment
        primary key,
    WORD    varchar(32) null,
    USER_ID int         null,
    constraint words_word_user_id_uindex
        unique (WORD, USER_ID),
    constraint words_user_user_id_fk
        foreign key (USER_ID) references USER (USER_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

а он и не добавится.
колонка id должна быть PRIMARY KEY (`id`) в USERS он не может повторяться.

если нужен контрольный в голову, то можно завести в таблице ещё ключ- уникальный по сумме двух полей -

```
CREATE TABLE `WORDS` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`names` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `Индекс 2` (`names`, `id`)
```

<.поскипано. >

как-то так